# MongoDB Aggregation - Group by, Select additional fields in result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been trying to use MongoDB Aggregation operator for getting the last record (based on 'fixtm' which is the fixtime). Each record has a device id, fixtime and some other information like latitude, longitude, speed etc. My below aggregation works fine in a way that it returns me the last record for each device. But how do I get the other fields like latitude, longitude etc? I have tried adding things like `lat: 1` in the $project list but no matter how many variations I have tried, the other values just don't show up. I think it's because they don't exist in the group operator's _id field or something? Any pointers will be greatly helpful. Thanks

```
function() {
    return db.gpspos.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $sort: {
                    devid: 1,
                    fixtm: 1
                }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$devid",
                    lastData: {
                        $last: "$fixtm"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    device_id: '$_id',
                    fixtime: '$lastData'
                }
            }
        ]
    )
}
```

What I am getting from the above is

```
{ "device_id" : 5, "fixtime" : 1462368405000 }
{ "device_id" : 4, "fixtime" : 1462372097000 }
```

What I am looking at is this

```
{ "device_id" : 5, "fixtime" : 1462368405000, "speed": 70.3, "lat": 103.33434 }
{ "device_id" : 4, "fixtime" : 1462372097000, "speed": 70.3, "lat": 101.33434 }
```

An example of a document in my MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5729dc83f5be2411fb28c7c3"
    },
    "devid": 5,
    "devnm": "M.M (Samsung S3)",
    "fixtm": 1462360893000,
    "addr": "{address}",
    "lat": 1.433775,
    "lon": 103.7859717,
    "spdkm": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample documents that you are getting with the result above?

Comment: Sure chridam, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return the other fields as well, you can use the same **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operator within your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation. This will return the corresponding fields from the last document for each group:

```
function() {
    return db.gpspos.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $sort: {
                    devid: 1,
                    fixtm: 1
                }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$devid",
                    lastData: { $last: "$fixtm" },
                    speed: { $last: "$spdkm" },
                    address: { $last: "$address" },
                    lat: { $last: "$lat" },
                    lon: { $last: "$lon" }
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    device_id: '$_id',
                    fixtime: '$lastData',
                    speed: 1,
                    address: 1,
                    lat: 1,
                    lon: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    )
}
```

Comment: oh so I would have to use the $last accumulator on other fields even though what I need is the last record based on fixtm (unix time)? So i guess it find the last record for fixtm first, and then the rest - so it won't affect what's returned? Is that the logic?

Comment: Think of the aggregation pipeline in Linux's "pipe" context; when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other i.e. the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So when you want to return fields in your final pipeline stage they should be resulting from the previous operator, and in this case the other fields should come from the `$group` pipeline. Just like in SQL, you can't use GROUP BY unless you use any of the aggregation functions. In MongoDB you will have to use the `$last` or $first`

Comment: Ok I am kinda getting it but only simple clarification - what if I need to include a field that's not numeric. For example say address (addr). How would $last hold against that? Sorry I am totally new to MongoDB, so trying to digest things slowly :)

Comment: `$last` always returns a value from the last document for each group, it can be any value (string, numerical etc)

Comment: If there is any other way you'd recommend that would be fine too. Basically all that I want is the last record for each device. Describing it in another way: Say I have 50 records for 5 devices. What I'd need is the last inserted record (fixtm) for each device, which means my result will show 5 records (based on last fixtim)